# What Can ELB Do That ALB Cannot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, infrastructure

In AWS, is there anything ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) can do that ALB (Application Load Balancer) cannot?

And if the answer is nothing, then is there any incentive to choose ELB over ALB?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Deciding on which one to recommend to a (hypothetical) client.

Comment: The general principal is you use ALB unless you have a need for a feature of another load balancer. If you do you prefer NLB over legacy ELB.

Answer (score 1):

ELB can pass through TCP protocol (non-HTTP/HTTPS) while ALB only works with HTTP/HTTPS.

If you need raw TCP and not use ELB then there is NLB - Network Load Balancer.

Other than that nah, there are some minor differences but for most usecases ALB is better because it’s usually cheaper and has more possibilities.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @MLu suggested, ELB does not support HTTP/2 ( https://cloudacademy.com/blog/application-load-balancer-vs-classic-load-balancer/ ), which to me is a deal breaker for any HTTPS service of 2020 and beyond.